# 受信者が設定されていない。とエラーメッセージが突然きました。

Tags: google-apps-script

今まで正常に機能していたものが突然エラーになってしまう事ってあるのでしょうか？
以下のような設定で自動返信をしています。ところが

> メールを送信できませんでした: 受信者が指定されていません（行 69、ファイル「コード」）

とエラーメッセージが出るようになりました。
全くの初心者で似たような事例を見つけられず困っています。どなたかご教示願います。

```js
/**
 * Googleフォーム自動返信スクリプト
 */

/**
 * 起点・設定
 */
function autoreply() {

 //自動返信メールの件名
 var title = "欠席連絡ありがとうございます。"; 

 //自動返信メールの本文　\nは改行。 
 var body
 = "欠席のご連絡ありがとうございました。\n"
 +"下記のとおり受け付けました。\n\n"
 + "------------------------------------------------------------\n";

 //自動返信メールの本文2　本文1と本文2の間に入力内容が入る 
 var body2
 = "------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"
 + "楽しい水泳　ヘッドコーチ　";

//後の処理で使うため、変数を設定。（フォームと名称を一致させる必要あり）  
 var name = '氏名';
 var mail = 'メールアドレス';
 var address = "";

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var row = sheet.getLastRow();
 var column = sheet.getLastColumn();
 var range = sheet.getDataRange();

 for (var i = 1; i <= column; i++ ) {

 //スプレッドシートの入力項目名
   var item = range.getCell(1, i).getValue(); 

 //スプレッドシートの入力値
   var value = range.getCell(row, i).getValue(); 

 //本文（body）に、フォームの入力項目を追加  
   body += "■"+item+"\n";

 //本文にフォームの入力内容を追加
   body += value + "\n\n";

 //フォームの入力項目が、「氏名」の場合は、「様」をつけて、本文の前に追加  
   if ( item === name ) {
     body = value+" 様\n\n"+body;
   }

 //フォームの入力項目が「メールアドレス」の場合は、変数addressに入れる
   if ( item === mail ) {
     address = value;
   }
 }

 //本文1に本文2を追加
  body += body2;

//宛名＝address、件名＝title、本文=bodyで、メールを送る
  GmailApp.sendEmail(address,title,body,{
    from:'swimmingclub.ogawa@gmail.com',name:'楽しい水泳　ヘッドコーチ'});
}
```

Comment: タグが`python`となっていますが、コードの内容とコメント「Googleフォーム自動返信スクリプト」を見る限り、`google-apps-script`の話ではないでしょうか？

Comment: スクリプトを読む限りはフォーム(スプレッドシート)に保存された情報を元にメールを送信しており、「受信者が指定されていません」のエラーは宛先のメールアドレスが取得出来ていないからではないでしょうか。シートに必要なデータが入力されているのかを確認してください。

Comment: タグはよくわからずこのようにしてしまいました。すみません。また、ご指摘のデータはシート上では入力されているように思います。

Comment: @ChikaKaminaga さん、こんにちは。どうやら質問者さんのアカウント「神永千佳」と今のアカウント「Chika Kaminaga」でアカウントが別になってしまっているように見えます。もしそうなのであれば、ヘルプセンターの[こちらのページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)からアカウントを 1 つにまとめられますので、お試しください。質問者のアカウントでしたら自由にコメントできます。

Answer (score 1):

> 今まで正常に機能していたものが突然エラーになってしまう事ってあるのでしょうか？

推測ですが、今までGoogleAppsScriptが動作していたスプレッドシートに変更が加えられてメールアドレスカラムを消してしまったのではないでしょうか？
スプレッドシートにメールアドレスというカラムがあるかどうか確認してみたらいかがでしょう。